# Scala shortest equivalent to c# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, scala, loops, collections

I need to create a bunch of new objects in scala
What is the shortest equivalent for the following C# code?

```
var n = 100;    
var persons = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(x=>new Person(x)).ToList();
```

and whats wrong with this?

```
val persons: List[Person] = (1 to n) map (new Person(_))
```

Comment: You just need to add a `toList` to the end.

Comment: oh, thank you, my stupidity. Is there a resharper for scala? Eclipse doesn't say much

Comment: @python_kaa no there is no such thing even remotely similar to R#

Comment: @om-nom-nom even not in IntelliJ IDEA? im too spoiled with R#...

Comment: they have Scala support, but R# is orders of magnitude way more advanced in a sence of language and frameworks features **coverage**. Having said this, JB Scala guys have done an awesome job, I use their plugin on a daily basis, they just don't have that much time and people

Comment: Does it really have to be a `List` specifically? Your method as it is gives you a `Seq[Person]` (implemented with a `Vector`) which should be good if not better for most uses

Comment: I agree with you, any collection is enough. But in this particular case I needed a List. The compiler complained about couldn't convert Seq to List or something similar. I didn't know about `toList` method and what to do with this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [List.range](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List%24):

```
List.range(1, n + 1).map(new Person(_))
```

Or as Lee suggested:

```
(1 to n).map(new Person(_)).toList
```

Calling `toList` is required because `(1 to n).map(new Person(_))` produces an `IndexedSeq[Person]`. Note also that the type of `1 to n` is [`Range.Inclusive`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range%24%24Inclusive) and that it is different to the type of `List.range(1, n + 1)` which is `List[Int]`.

Comment: The second argument to `Enumerable.Range` is a count, so you need to use `List.range(1, n + 1)`

Comment: @FrankS.Thomas thank you. Is it usually in scala to use points instead of just spaces? And what is the difference between `(1 to n)` and `List.range(1, n + 1)` ?

Comment: @python_kaa List.range is used when you want a specific collection like list, seq or perhaps iterator (so there will be List.range, Seq.range, Iterator.range, etc). Those functions are not limited to only range: if you wouldn't be restricted to base 1, you could use even shorter form: `List.tabulate(n)(new Person(_))`. Note also there is a much more common method .fill which is used for a little different purpouse (just N things, index is not used). (1 to n) is a generic form, usually it is used with map, foreach operations followed by cast to desired collection (like .toList, toArray).

Comment: @python_kaa `(1 to n)` is used much more commonly, just because not everyone out there know about collections companion methods

Comment: @python_kaa With regards to dots or spaces for method invocation: that's a matter of personal style. In most cases I like to use dots because it is clearer on which object the mehotd is invoked.